# Send individual bluetooth LE packet from command line

Tags: networking, bluetooth, wireshark

I have a Bluetooth-controlled 'Smart Plug' to control appliances. I want to be able to control it using programs of my own devising, rather than just the manufacturer's proprietary app.

I know how to pair form the command line using `bluetoothctl`, and *have already gotten as far as using Wireshark to identify the packets being sent & received when I switch the plug on or off in the app.* Now, all I need is a way to actually send the LE packets/requests from the command line (I did not anticipate that **this** was where I would get stuck...).

I have no previous experience developing with Bluetooth, but ideally I would like something of the form:

`send-packet <target MAC address> <contents of packet>`

Is this possible?

Comment: _What kind_ of packets, specifically? I would be guessing GATT for Bluetooth LE, but I mean it could just as well be "traditional" Bluetooth with HID or SPP or something weirder.

Comment: The device is listed as LE when pairing. Otherwise I'm afraid I'm flying blind here - as said, I have no previous experience using Bluetooth devices as anything other than an end user.

Answer (score 0):

Might "Home Assistant" be an option?

It is a LOT more than you ask for, though.

Ref: https://www.home-assistant.io/
-> "Home Assistant integrates with over a thousand different devices and services."